Why does OnUnitActiveSec starts on the hour, sharp?
I wrote a timer for a backup service:
[Unit]
Description=runs borg every 3 hours

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=3h

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

When starting it at 17:29 I see:
root@srv /e/docker# systemctl list-timers borg
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST PASSED UNIT       ACTIVATES
Fri 2024-08-09 20:00:02 CEST 2h 27min left -    -      borg.timer borg.service

This suggests that systems scheduled the call in 2 hours 30 minutes, to run it sharp at the hour. When reading the documentation for OnUnitActiveSec, I was under the impression that it would start the service right away, and then every 3 hours

Change WantedBy=multi-user.target to WantedBy=timers.target. I would also add Persistent=true under "[Timer]".

@ajgringo619 I did that, restarted but nothing changed

Restarted the timer, or restarted the computer? I would try a clean reboot, if nothing else is working.

If you want the timer to start the service immediately you need to add OnActiveSec=0, ie 0 seconds after the .timer is started.. Since OnUnitActiveSec= is time after the .service is started, and it has never yet been started in your case, I suppose it is a bit vague about when to start it for the first time?
